# How to calculate $\sum_i^m \sum_j^n x_i x_j (\phi_i^T \phi_j)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, matrix-equations

I'm wondering how to tackle down and calculate the following equation efficiently:

$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_i x_j (\phi_i^T \phi_j)$

Am I allowed to do this?

$(\sum_i^m x_i) (\sum_j^n x_j) (\sum_i^m \sum_j^n(\phi_i^T \phi_j))$

And if so, how do I calculate $\sum_i^m \sum_j^n(\phi_i^T \phi_j)$?

What's exactly the difference between $\sum_i^m \sum_j^n(\phi_i^T \phi_j)$ and $\sum_i^m \sum_j^n(\phi_i \phi_j)$ in this case?

Note that $x$ and $\phi$ are $n\times 1$ vectors

Comment: Hey, can you please clarify what $\sum_i^m$ means?

Comment: From i = 1, ..., m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to achieve, and your notation could do with some clarification. I did my best to decipher what you are asking.

---

You are *not* allowed to do that series manipulation. Since $x_i$ is constant with respect to the index $j$, the best you can do is $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i\sum_{j=1}^m x_j(\phi_i^T\phi_j)$. The rest must remain under the same series.

In general, you cannot split a series in the following way: $\sum ab \to \sum a\sum b$. Think of the difference between the sum $x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3$ and $(x_1+x_2+x_3)(y_1+y_2+y_3)$.

If, as you say, $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ are $m\times1$ and $n\times 1$ vectors respectively (i.e., column vectors), then $\phi_i^T\phi_j$ is only defined when $m=n$, and it is equal to their dot product $\langle\phi_i,\phi_j\rangle$. On the other hand, $\phi_i\phi_j$ is not even defined.

---

**Edit**:  OP, you have edited your question so that $x_i$ and $x_j$ are also vectors. In this case, $x_ix_j(\phi_i^T\phi_j)$ does not make any sense.

Comment: Forgive me for being vague. Let's say that we have $[x_1, ... , x_4]$ = [1, 2, 3, 4], $[x_5, ..., x_{10}]$ = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and same goes for $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$. Does this makes sense?

Comment: What do you think the product $x_ix_j(\phi^T_i\phi_j)$ would mean in that case?

Comment: As for the $\sum \sum x_i x_j$ part this would be $1(5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10) + ... +  
  4(5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10)$
However, I'm not sure about the $\phi_i^T \phi_j$ part

Comment: So hang on, $x_i$ is a number, not a vector; and $(x_1,\dots,x_4)$ and $(x_5,\dots,x_{10})$ are vectors, let's get that terminology clear. Now what you wrote there, $\sum x_ix_j$, is *not* the sum you expressed, what you expressed is equivalent to $(1+2+3+4)(5+6+\cdots+10) = (\sum_{i=1}^4x_i)(\sum_{j=5}^{10} x_j)$. Do you understand the difference? And what does $\phi_i^T\phi_j$ even mean? You have to tell me that, I can't decipher it.

Comment: $\phi$ should have the same characteristics as $x$, same length. That's why I was wondering why the authors specifically chose the put a transpose in it.
But to be sure, $(\sum_i^m x_i) (\sum_j^n x_j) (\sum_i^m \sum_j^n(\phi_i^T \phi_j))$ is correct?

Comment: Depends on the context though. And you can only transpose a vector, not a number. If $\phi_i$ is the same as $x_i$, then $\phi_i$ is a number for each $i$, so the transpose makes no sense. Could you add a reference for context?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the factorization machine eq.(7) proposed in the paper "Basket-Sensitive Personalized Item Recommendation" by Le et al. (2017). However, after rereading through the paper there was a big misunderstanding. Each $\phi_i \in R^K$ is a K-dimensional latent vector associated with $i^{th}$ component which makes sense now, as it is now a dot product

Comment: So everything is clear?

Comment: Now my last question: is the following transformation $(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i) (\sum_{j = m+1}^n x_j) (\sum_i^m \sum_j^n(\phi_i^T \phi_j))$ valid in this case? where $\phi_i^T \phi_j$ is a dot product